# Error when launching java program from C#

Tags: c#, java, launching-application

I trying to launch java program with this code:

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
        info.WorkingDirectory = @"D:\2\server";
        info.FileName = "java";
        info.Arguments = "-Xms512m -Xmx1536m -Xbootclasspath/p:./libs/jsr166.jar -cp ./libs/*;server.jar server.Server";
        ServerProcess = new Process();
        ServerProcess.StartInfo = info;
        ServerProcess.Start();
```

But always getting error:

> Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough
>   space for object heap Could not create the Java virtual machine.

But if i create a .bat file with code:

```
java -Xms512m -Xmx1536m -Xbootclasspath/p:./libs/jsr166.jar -cp ./libs/*;server.jar server.Server
```

- all ok!

So i guess something wrong with my C# code?

Thanks!

Comment: May be try removing "FileName" and add "java inside arguments?

Comment: Perhaps your C# application is taking a lot of memory?

Comment: No, with starting all ok, problem with working this launcher java application, seems like this launcher program works kinda isolated

Comment: @AljoshaBre, no its about 15m )

Comment: Is it happening every time? Did you try running it on a freshly booted machine?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps, but I do know the Process object does have a limit of memory it allocates for the process.  Since the batch file works, I think the JVM's heap allocation exceeds the Peak Memory allowed for the associated process.  Unfortunately, I do not know of any way to increase the maximum memory allocated by the Process object.

I would vote either stick with the batch file approach or use IKVM:  http://www.ikvm.net/ or use jni4net:  http://jni4net.sourceforge.net/.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue a lot for a while, when launching from a .NET application you must remove the memory allocation commands. In your case here is the correct command:

```
    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
    info.WorkingDirectory = @"D:\2\server";
    info.FileName = "java";
    info.Arguments = "-Xbootclasspath/p:./libs/jsr166.jar -cp ./libs/*;server.jar server.Server";
    ServerProcess = new Process();
    ServerProcess.StartInfo = info;
    ServerProcess.Start();
```

That's what worked for me at least.